# Somebody can explain me this struct?

Tags: c++, struct, graph-theory

I'm working on a Graph Theory Algorithm. I know what is a graph and what is an edge etc. I have this first part of this script in c++ where it declares some variables and some struct, and after it defines a function that adds an edge.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int M = 500;
struct struct_edge
{
    int v; 
    struct_edge * n;  
};

typedef struct_edge * edge;  
struct_edge pool[M * M * 2]; 
edge top = pool, adj[M];    
int V, E, match[M], qh, qt, q[M], father[M], base[M];   
bool inq[M], inb[M], ed[M][M];   
void add_edge(int u, int v)
{
    top->v = v, top->n = adj[u], adj[u] = top++;
    top->v = u, top->n = adj[v], adj[v] = top++;
}
```

If this isn't enough I'll put an other part of the script.
I have some problem to understand why the struct_edge has a pointer to an other struct_edge (it's an edge not a node!). And I have some serious problem to understand this declaration:
    edge top = pool, adj[M]; 
top is a pointer to a struct_edge and it has an array of struct and an array of int at the interior?!?
For a full code you can see this link
http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/49402

Comment: Dont't include <bits/stdc++.h>, it's a non standard header not meant for inclusion.

Comment: this isnt a "script" it is code that needs to get compiled. No native speaker here, but it feels wrong to call c++ code a "script"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first problem, the graph is stored as an *adjacency list* format. Each node has an associated *linked list* of edges (`struct_edge`), each of which has an index (`int v;`) to the node at the end of the edge, and a pointer to the next edge (`struct_edge* n;`). The index is to the `adj[M]` array, which stores the `M` nodes that make up the graph.

Second problem, `pool` is a statically declared array of `struct_edge`, and the OP uses this to make a *stack allocator*, i.e. the new nodes are allocated by incrementing `top`, which is a pointer to the top of the stack. `top` is initialized to `pool` which is the base of the stack (start of the array).

EDIT: A diagram of the pointer arrangement for the wikimedia graph you linked:

[image]

(Note the indices start from 0 instead of 1, so Node 1 in the graph diagram corresponds to `v = 0` in the code)

Comment: I think I have understood but there is already something obscure on the first part. For example in a simple situation like this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Liste_di_adiacenza.svg/220px-Liste_di_adiacenza.svg.png. The node 1 has two struct_edge: the first has int v=2 (because it's the end of the edge) and what is the address of the pointer? the second has int v=3 and again, what is the address of the pointer?

Comment: @AlessandroPicardi first one has `int v = 1` because indices start from zero; by pointer which one do you mean? The `next` pointer or the pointer to the `struct_edge` itself?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out your sentence "Each node has an associated linked list of edges (struct_edge), each of which has an index (int v;) to the node at the end of the edge, and a pointer to the next edge (struct_edge* n;)". 
So The node 1 in the photo has an assosiated linked list of edges (I think that the node one has the edge 1-3 and 1-2) and for each of this two edges we has an index and a pointer to the next egde. So the edge 1-3 is a struct_edge with int v=3 and I don't understand the pointer to the next edge.

Comment: @AlessandroPicardi I think I'll upload a diagram showing the connections and pointers, just to avoid all these tl;dr descriptions

Comment: @alessandropicardi I uploaded a diagram, hope it helps